# Find grammar for the following language: $\{ a^{m_1}ba^{m_2}b\dots a^{m_k}bca^n \mid m_j = n \text{ for some } 1 \le j \le k \}$

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I need to Find grammar for the following language: $\{ a^{m_1}ba^{m_2}b\dots a^{m_k}bca^n \mid m_j = n \text{ for some } 1 \le j \le k \}$.

can someone help me to solve it? I am not sure how to start.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? If you can't even start, you need to review your course materials, textbook and so on. Producing a grammar for any given language is a creative act: you can't just expect to follow some recipe.

Answer (score 3):

First try to understand the form of the strings in the language. If $m_j=n$ then strings are of the form $\dots a^n b \dots c a^n$. What is on the place of the dots?

Comment: I understand that but i don't understand how i make the a^n to be equal to the a^mj

Comment: I guess you can make a grammar for $\{a^nba^n\mid n\ge1\}$.

Comment: Cute. We all understand that you meant to write $\dotsc a^n\dotsc ca^n$ in your answer.